# Apigee target endpoint timeout

Tags: apigee

Is there a way to check the target endpoint timeout in the post flow. Basically I want my api to respond with a specific message, if target endpoint does not respond in a specific period of time.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to have a look at the [endpoint properties reference](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/reference/endpoint-properties-reference); it's got a selection of details you can use to configure timeouts.

Particularly, in your case, you'd want to set `connect.timeout.millis` to something suitable, then handle that error in your `DefaultFaultHandler`. You can read up on [fault handling](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/fault-handling) for more details on customization.